# Maven setup on Microsoft hosted agent

Tags: maven, azure-devops

I am building the java code using azure devops ci-cd pipeline using Microsoft hosted agent
The hosted agent has maven 3.8.1 version, whereas I want to use maven 3.6.3 via wrapper.
I tried the command mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper in command line task and then executed package goal however the build is picking up the preinstalled version.

Wrapper contents are as follows:

```
distributionUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.6.3/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip
wrapperUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/takari/maven-wrapper/0.5.6/maven-wrapper-0.5.6.jar
```

Any help on how to use different version via wrapper would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the wrapper is that it shouldn't matter what version your "agent" has. If the "agent" already has maven, then you don't need the wrapper

You can see [in the changelog](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) that 3.8 isn't available, and in the README, it was written that the goal was to include the wrapper as part of Maven 3.7 (I'm not sure if that happened), but the takari project is effectively frozen and you should consult the migration notes at the top of the README

> executed package goal however the build is picking up the preinstalled version.

Maybe because you're running the `mvn` command from the PATH rather than `mvnw` from the project directory

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I installed the maven 3.6.3 on microsoft hosted agent, how can I setup a path for maven and how can I edit settings.xml